# Does Armadillo run well with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE*?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++builder, armadillo

I plan to purchase Embarcadero C++Builder XE* and later install Armadillo C++ linear algebra library , so I can work on the sparse matrix type of projects. Before I purchase C++ Builder XE* from Embarcadero, I just wonder if Armadillo works well with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE*. I think lots of you run Armadillo, do some of you run Armadillo in Embarcadero C++BuilderXE2~4? Does Armadillo run well there?

Thanks for feedback.

Eddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) requires a C++ compiler that can properly handle [template meta-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming): the compiler has to properly support the C++ standard.

Is there a particular reason you need the Embarcadero C++ Builder ?

These days we have the luxury of very high quality C++ compilers that are both free (no-cost) and open-source.  You may wish to look into compilers such as GCC and Clang, which can be used in conjunction with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org).

All Linux distributions come with GCC pre-compiled.  You can get GCC for Windows from the [MinGW project](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: C++ Builder for 64 bit is based off of CLANG 3.1 so it should compile Armadillo.  You'd have to test the 32 bit compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C++Builder's 32-bit compiler has several issues with more complicated C++ constructs, so it's not unusual for me to have to do some porting work to get C++ libraries to build in it.  All other things being equal, I'd recommend another compiler.

I have no experience with Armadillo in particular, but Embarcadero has a [free trial](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/rad_studio) available, so you should be able to try it yourself.